# AD B2C - I should have the capability to link my accounts with same email id for different authentication options

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

As a G2C User\B2B Portal User, I should have the capability to link my accounts with the same email id for different authentication options, so that I can have a single account in CRM

Is this possible? How to achieve this?

Users with multiple login options must have the same email id linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either give the user the ability to link accounts manually by implementing the following sample: [Link and Unlink Accounts](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/account-linkage-unified)

Or if you want to automatically link accounts based on email address you can follow the [Auto Account Linking](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/auto-account-linking) sample.